# How can I read smart card id?

Tags: java, smartcard

I am learning Java smart card API.

Using `pcsc_scan` on Ubuntu, it says that the card is not listed in `smartcard_list.txt` and the ATR is proprietary.

As I understand I must know how the data is written in order to read it with APDU commands but since its proprietary, it may be a problem.

I just want to get the ID of the card and no other information. Is that possible or not?

Comment: So what have you tried in terms of the Java smartcardio API? The output you get from the `pcsc_scan` tool only tells you that the card is not known (ie. not listed in the smartcard_list.txt). That's not necessarily a problem.

Comment: What card are you using? What card reader are you using?